# Re-Projection a view openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I'm new to GIS and OL3. My app needs to display a map in EPSG:4326 and the same app has to display a map in EPSG:3412 when I click on a button.

Here is the link for the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tmylamoule/ze9cg462/

My JS code

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3412", "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs");
var ePSG3412Button = document.getElementById('clickMe');
var ePSG3857Button = document.getElementById('clickMe2');


var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
        layer: 'sat',
        wrapX: false,
        noWrap: true,
      }),
    })
  ],
});
ePSG3412Button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var view2 = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3412',
    center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:3412'),
    zoom: 1
  });
  map.setView(view2);
});
ePSG3857Button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    center: ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 1
  });
  map.setView(view);
});
```

The only thing my code is doing is center the map in the middle of each projection. But I can't manage to transform the tiles.

Comment: I think you cannot reproject "Image" and "Tile" sources, but I find no references in the documentation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer ! 
From what I've found [link](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/reprojection-by-code.html)
It is possible to reproject but the example in the URL won't work on jsfiddle :(

Comment: You are right, I was remember wrongly. So it is possible

Comment: Yes I know it's possible but I can't make this possible in my app :(

Comment: Tile reprojection is possible with the latest versions of ol3. I think 3.12 and above. Within your fiddle you use v3.0.0. try to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: Holy sh*t ! Thanks for the answer pavlos ! This works great now. Just wasted 3 hours searching things while it was only a version problem ^^

Comment: hehehe glad to help amigo

Comment: @pavlos: this question seems solved. Could you (or the OP) expand your comment into an answer, so that the question could be removed from "unanswered questions"? Also, the question got some upvotes, so it's quite probable that it will help someone else and as a proper answer it will be more visible.

Comment: thats true. I have just added an answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

From  v3.11.0 and above ol3 library supports raster reprojection on client. So tile reprojection is also possible. release notes stating this change may be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.11.0).

If anyone faces kind of this problem , upgrade to the latest ol3 version.